# Configuring Bro-IDS

Tags: 12.04

I wanna Install Bro-IDS 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04
I've installed the following stage:

```
export PATH=/nsm/bro/bin:$PATH
```

then
Configuring Bro-IDS------------>Configuring the node.cfg file
how do I change  node.cfg file?

```
root@ubuntu:~# nsm/bro/etc/node.cfg
```

error:

```
-su: nsm/bro/etc/node.cfg: No such file or directory
```

when I open node.cfg with `nano node.cfg`, file is empty!!!!!
what do I do?

Comment: Did you `nano /nsm/bro/etc/node.cfg`? Because unless you're in the `node.cfg` directory, `nano node.cfg` is going to make a new file called `node.cfg` in your current directory.

Comment: With nano /nsm/bro/etc/node.cfg, node.cfg file was observed (Is like cat /nsm/bro/etc/node.cfg?)

Comment: Yes, except it's an actual editor. So putting the full path in worked?

Comment: yes,thanks.Did I do something to change? in node.cfg,networks.cfg , broctl.cfg files.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your question was just about why you couldn't edit that file. If you want help with the rest of the installation, you're going to have to make a new question and actually link the guide you're following.

Comment: in link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-bro-ids-2-2-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: "you're going to have to make a new question and actually link the guide you're following."

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/817829/configuring-the-node-cfg-networks-cfg-broctl-cfg-files-in-install-bro-ids

Answer (score 1):

Just running `nano node.cfg` isn't going to do much, since you're not actually in the directory the config file is in.

Judging from the terminal paste you show, you are in the default directory for the terminal: your home directory. That's `~/` (relative) or `/home/USERNAME/` (absolute).

`node.cfg` is under `/nsm/bro/etc/node.cfg`, while your terminal is in `/home/USERNAME/`. Running `nano node.cfg` will look for `/home/USERNAME/node.cfg` in this case. If it doesn't exist (which it doesn't), nano will create a blank file to edit.

Run `nano /nsm/bro/etc/node.cfg` to edit the file, or run `cd /nsm/bro/etc/` to move your terminal into the same directory as `node.cfg` and run `nano node.cfg`.

In the off-chance that you thought running `nano node.cfg` would be fine because you added that directory to the PATH, well, you didn't. The guide says to add `/nsm/bro/bin/`, while your config is under `/nsm/bro/etc/`.